# Warning while I am calculating eigenvalues

Tags: r, warnings, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, symmetric

I have to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but I always have this warning. I hope someone can tell me what's going on.

```
#masa en kg
m1=559.3e-3
m2=419.4e-3
m3=m2
m4=m2
m5=m2
m6=m2
m7=m2
m8=m2
#rigidez en N/m
k=56.7e3
#matrices de masa y rigidez
M=matrix(c(m1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,m2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,m3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,m4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,m5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,m6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,m7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,m8), 8, 8, byrow=TRUE)
K=matrix(c(k,-k,0,0,0,0,0,0,-k,2*k,-k,0,0,0,0,0,0,-k,2*k,-k,0,0,0,0,0,0,-k,2*k,-k,0,0,0,0,0,0,-k,2*k,-k,0,0,0,0,0,0,-k,2*k,-k,0,0,0,0,0,0,-k,2*k,-k,0,0,0,0,0,0,-k,k), 8, 8, byrow=TRUE)
#calculo valores y vectores propios
a=eigen(K,M)

>Warning message:
In if (symmetric) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: It means it calculates only the eigen value of the first element which is `K` in this setting, run `eigen(K,M)` and `eigen(K)` . You will see that it will give the same output.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that the variable `symmetric` (probably internal to the `eigen` function) is evaluating to a logical vector with length greater than one. When this happens in the condition of an if statement, only the first element is used.

The documentation leads me to think that you want to pass each matrix to the function separately.

```
a <- eigen(K)
b <- eigen(M)
```

Use `?eigen` to view the help for this function, which suggests it's only expecting one argument to be a matrix.

EDIT: Below you can find the code that defines the `eigen()` function. In the RStudio IDE, you can hover over a function and press F2 to get the code for the function. Based on this, when you give `M` as the second argument to the `eigen()` function, it is interpreting it as `eigen(x = K, symmetric = M)`. It expects for `symmetric` to be `TRUE`, `FALSE` or missing, but instead it is getting a matrix. When it gets to the line where `symmetric` is used as the condition for an `if` statement, it throws this warning.

```
function (x, symmetric, only.values = FALSE, EISPACK = FALSE) 
{
  x <- unname(as.matrix(x))
  n <- nrow(x)
  if (!n) 
    stop("0 x 0 matrix")
  if (n != ncol(x)) 
    stop("non-square matrix in 'eigen'")
  n <- as.integer(n)
  if (is.na(n)) 
    stop("invalid nrow(x)")
  complex.x <- is.complex(x)
  if (!all(is.finite(x))) 
    stop("infinite or missing values in 'x'")
  if (missing(symmetric)) 
    symmetric <- isSymmetric.matrix(x)
  if (symmetric) {                    # Here is the line generating the error
    z <- if (!complex.x) 
      .Internal(La_rs(x, only.values))
    else .Internal(La_rs_cmplx(x, only.values))
    ord <- rev(seq_along(z$values))
  }
  else {
    z <- if (!complex.x) 
      .Internal(La_rg(x, only.values))
    else .Internal(La_rg_cmplx(x, only.values))
    ord <- sort.list(Mod(z$values), decreasing = TRUE)
  }
  if (only.values) 
    list(values = z$values[ord], vectors = NULL)
  else structure(class = "eigen", list(values = z$values[ord], 
    vectors = z$vectors[, ord, drop = FALSE]))
}
```